# How to pass values from C# / Razor to angularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to pass a value from my C#/Razor to angularJS.

I tried this:

```
{{isDashboardOpened=@((ViewContext.Controller.GetUserSettings(this.User).ShowDashboardOnLoad).ToString().ToLower());""}}
```

It didnt work well, because after this I can't change my variable any more.

Here is the rest of my code:

```
 <li id="btnDashboard" ng-click="toggleDashboard()" ng-class="{'active':isDashboardOpened}">
                        <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" title="@ResourcesLocal.Widgets.Resources_WidgetBase.Dashboard"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>


angular.module("frigodataOnline")
.controller("ProjectViewController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.isDashboardOpened = false;

    $scope.toggleDashboard = function () {
        $scope.isDashboardOpened = !$scope.isDashboardOpened;
    };

    $scope.openDashboard = function () {
        $scope.isDashboardOpened = true;
    };

    $scope.closeDashboard = function () {
        $scope.isDashboardOpened = false;
    };
}]);
```

When I havent implement my frst line (razor to ang) then my toggle work, if I implement it, the toggle doesnt work any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-init

```
<li id="btnDashboard" ng-click="toggleDashboard()" ng-init="isDashboardOpened='@((ViewContext.Controller.GetUserSettings(this.User).ShowDashboardOnLoad).ToString().ToLower());' ng-class="{'active':isDashboardOpened}">
                    <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" title="@ResourcesLocal.Widgets.Resources_WidgetBase.Dashboard"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
```